# Are Resharper's warnings about closures correct?

Tags: c#, closures, resharper

Today I faced following situation

```
public async Task<Stream> GetApproveDocumentAsync<T>(Guid id, int revision, PdfLayoutType pdfLayoutType, string resourceFilePath, CadDrawingType cadDrawingType, int approvalWidth, int approvalHeight, Action<T> fillModelAction = null) where T : BaseApproveModel, new() {
    var previewFileName = $"{id}_{revision}_preview.png";
    Stream previewFile;
    using (var resourceFileStream = new FileStream(resourceFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true)) {
        previewFile = await _cadApiService.ConvertDrawingToImageAsync(resourceFileStream, cadDrawingType, FileFormat.EVD, FileFormat.PNG, approvalWidth, approvalHeight).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    Func<string[], T> createBaseApproveModelFunc = graphicContentFilenames => { //Implicitly captured closure: previewFile
         var model = new T {
             GraphicContentFiles = graphicContentFilenames,
             CadPreview = previewFileName,
             Customer = _userService.GetCurrentOverrideCustomer()?.CustomerName
         };
         fillModelAction?.Invoke(model);
         return model;
    };
    Action<List<StreamWithFileName>> fillGraphicContentAction = currentGraphicContent => { //Implicitly captured closure: fillModelAction, this
        currentGraphicContent.Add(new StreamWithFileName {FileName = previewFileName, Stream = previewFile});
    };
    return await _apagoService.ConstcutPdf(pdfLayoutType, createBaseApproveModelFunc, fillGraphicContentAction).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I thought I know how closures work, but I can't understand ReSharper behaviour. Is ReSharper swap these two warnings by mistake (or bug)?

I'm using ReSharper Ultimate 2016.2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* that what resharper is telling you is that those two closures are *also* capturing additional things that your code **doesn't think it is using** in that lambda. The first closure uses `previewFileName` and `this` (for the field `_userService`), so your capture of those is clearly intentional - but : it might not be obvious to you that you're also capturing `previewFile`. The reason you capture additional things is because the **scope** of the items captured is the same, so the compiler generates a single closure to capture all of `previewFile`, `this`, `previewFileName` and `fillModelAction` - and the closure instance has **two** methods - one for the `Func<string[], T>` and one for the `Action<List<StreamWithFileName>>`. Note that `previewFileName` is used by both lambdas, so: no warning.

Understanding this may be important for garbage collection reasons - if one lambda lived much longer than the other, you might not want to keep additional things alive accidentally, hence the warning. For example, the `fillGraphicContentAction` lambda keeps the entire `this` alive (whatever `this` is), even though the lambda doesn't use `this`.